# Constant defined in header.php not visible in functions.php

Tags: constants

I have defined constant in header.php file:

```
define( 'HOME_URL', esc_url( home_url() ) );
```

and used in functions.php file:

```
function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    ob_start(); ?>

    <div class="cart-customlocation">
        <img class="cart-img align-top" src="<?php echo HOME_URL . '/wp-content/uploads/icons/header/cart.png'; ?>" >
        <div id="cart-count" class="d-inline-block"><?php echo WC()->cart->cart_contents_count; ?></div>
        <div class="cart-description d-inline-block ml-4">
            <div id="cart-title">Cart</div>
            <div id="cart-total"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    $fragments['div.cart-customlocation'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;

    ob_start();
    ?>

    <div class="mini-cart">
        
        <?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?>
        
    </div>

    <?php
    $fragments['div.mini-cart'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment' );
```

and getting notice: `<b>Warning</b>:  Use of undefined constant HOME_URL - assumed 'HOME_URL'...`

Comment: `header.php` comes after `functions.php`, from your code there should be no problem puting the define at the top of the `functions.php`, before your actions and filters. This functions `esc_url( home_url() )` will be available in `functions.php`

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. Create please an answer and I will mark it as solution.